# Does GZIP Compression helps the database images?

Tags: mysql, server, phpmyadmin, gzip

I have a website without any public content just a blank page. I use a database with images for my android app and i would like to ask you if GZIP compression will help on that. I know that it helps in public content but what about databases?

Comment: GZIP in general works the best on repeating text, images are binary data so that will not compress that much... Maybe use *"Delta encoding"*

Comment: Please add what you're trying to achieve...is database local? how large are the images? how many images? which phones are you targeting? What format? Why do you store images in a database and not in a file system? ie "I want to load 10k images and they are all 2kb in size" would already get you a different answer than "I want to load 3 images each 2gb"

Comment: I have an android TV app with public channels. From my admin panel im uploading the logos of my channels and the link url. Before uploading images im using tinyPNG. Also all images have rectangle dimensions up to 400x400. I would like to minify somehow all the image sizes of my database to decrease the bandwidth.